# Is there a general word for the letter/numeral used in enumerating a list?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if I have a list

1. First Item
2. Second Item
3. Third Item

or

```
 A. First Item
 B. Second
 C. Third
```

or

```
i. First
ii. Second
iii. Third
```

Is there a general term for the symbol denoting the enumeration of each item? e.g. in first example, it's the numbers 1, 2, and 3; second it's A, B, C, and third it's i, ii, iii.

Answer (score 2):

The number denoting the position of an element in a list is the **"index"**

Answer (score 1):

You could call it a *counter* in an *ordered list.* (That's what it's called in HTML.)

Some might still call it a *number* in a *numbered list*, even if your items actually begin with a capital or small letter instead of a number. (That is, in fact, what Microsoft Word seems to call these.)

In this Wikipedia article about [outlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_%28list%29), those numbers and letters are called *prefixes.*